# TStringList to TStringGrid

Tags: delphi

This is my first post and I am still learning a lot about Delphi and general programming. So please feel free to teach.

I am trying to populate a TStringList with column names from Access. Then display them in a TStringGrid. I am currently getting an "Array Type required" error. But I fear there may be more.

```pascal
procedure TFormDB1DataMapping.FieldNamesToGrid();
var
  myFieldnames: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if not Form1.ConnIn1.Connected then begin
    try
      //Set Connection Parameters and connect
      Form1.ConnIn1Parameters;
      Form1.ConnIn1.Connected:=True
    finally
    end;
  end;
  myFieldnames := TStringList.Create;
  Form1.ConnIn1.GetFieldNames('','',Form1.ComboBoxDB1TableName.Text,'',myFieldnames);
  StringGridDB1.RowCount := StringGridDB1.RowCount + 1;
  for I:= StringGridDB1.RowCount - 1 downto 1 do
    StringGridDB1.Rows[I] := StringGridDB1.Rows[I - 1];
  StringGridDB1.Cols[0][1] := myFieldnames.Text;
  myFieldnames.Free;
End;
```

[image]

Working procedure with answer below

```pascal
procedure TFormDB1DataMapping.FieldNamesToGrid();
var
  myFieldnames: TStringList;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if not Form1.ConnIn1.Connected then begin
    try
      //Set Connection Parameters and connect
      Form1.ConnIn1Parameters;
      Form1.ConnIn1.Connected:=True
    finally
    end;
  end;
  myFieldnames := TStringList.Create;
  Form1.ConnIn1.GetFieldNames('','',Form1.ComboBoxDB1TableName.Text,'',myFieldnames);
  StringGridDB1.RowCount := StringGridDB1.RowCount + 1;
  StringGridDB1.RowCount := myFieldnames.Count + 1;
  for I := 0 to myFieldnames.Count - 1 do
    StringGridDB1.Cells[0, I + 1] := myFieldnames[I];
  myFieldnames.Free;
End;
```

[image]

Comment: A TStringList is an object that contains a list of strings. It is not an array of strings. I presume GetFieldNames is expecting an array of strings.

Comment: Dsm Thank you for your answer. Get field names is from the TFDConnection. The error happens here.   'StringGridDB1.Col[1,myFieldnames];//:= myFieldnames;'

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Where in the StringGrid shall the column names appear?

Comment: What 're you trying to do really? Where you stuck in?

Comment: @Dsm [`FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.GetFieldNames`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.GetFieldNames)

Comment: You'll find an example of using `GetFieldNames` at the bottom of the link @Sami provided you.

Comment: I have made some progress and have updated my post.Now I need to figure out how to list the field names vertically instead of in one cell. I hope this provided some clarity. Thank you all for the assistance.

Comment: Your code will leak in the face of exceptions. You need to learn about try/finally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the field names in the first column sparing the top row for the  header, you can do that with the following code:

```
StringGrid1.RowCount := myFieldnames.Count + 1;
for I := 0 to myFieldnames.Count - 1 do
  StringGrid1.Cells[0, I + 1] := myFieldnames[I];
```

Comment: That works perfectly. I will update my post with the full code for anyone else who may have this Issue. Thank you everyone for your time